# Hints for the logic of django app

Tags: django, django-sessions, django-users

I'm learning Django and for this reason I'm developing an application described below.

This application allows users (authenticated and anonymous) to send message to other users.

Authenticated users can send message and can track all messages simply as all application that uses this feature. (like Facebook messages, for example)

The problem are anonymous users. I would an anonymous user can send message to other users but he can track his messages **only** for his session. Users can also reply to a message of an anonymous user but If an anonymous user lost his session lost also his messages.

The problem is, how can I manage anonymous user and their messages for the session only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django supports anonymous sessions.

If your app is relatively simple (it sounds like it is), I would do the following:

1. Create a standard Django user profile model and link that to the users messages but do not use OneToOne to connect to User.
2. Use database backed sessions (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions)
3. Create a temporary user profile model for anonymous users and store
   their temporary profile id in their session.
4. Once a day delete all profile objects that do not have a user AND
   whose id is not in the sessions table.  A simple way (and what I would do) is have a created date/time field on the profile and just delete any profile that was created two weeks or more ago and has a null user field.  I'd just crontab a django management command.

The cool thing is that if somebody registers after using the app anonymously for a while you can use their temporary profile as their profile and they keep their messages.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. Am I asking so much if I ask you to write some code for your method? Thank you dude!

Comment: My doubts are: should I create two user profile models? Why don't use OneToOne to connect to User? How can I clean the old profile objects every day?

Comment: Actually you could use OneToOne now that I think of it.  Just make sure you allow it to be null.  You shouldn't create two user profile models for a simple app.   If your app is complex (and the profile contains a lot of stuff) then you'll want another model that connects from profiles to your messages and have that referenced in the sessions.

Comment: So I should create the classic UserProfile model but with the OneToOne user set to `null = True`. Then I need to set a session variable `profile_id`. But it isn't insecure? An user can change its value and see the message of another user.

Comment: If you are using cookie backed sessions it would be insecure.  But with session backed the user can't access that info at all ... see this http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter20/